# How can I connect to a WiFi network in Windows 8.1 that has been forgotten?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

On Windows 8.1, a wifi network was marked as "Forget", but now I want to connect to that network and I can't even see the network.

I tried adding the connection manually, and that didn't work. I deleted the profile associated with the network, and restarted, but that didn't work. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Can other devices see this network because all "Forget" does is removes the store creditionals for the network.

Comment: They could, and they could connect fine. But after hitting "Forget", it didn't show in the list at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently the issue was I needed to use the "Hidden Network" option and be sure to type in the network id there (being sure to capitalize correctly).